# Using Typedoc with aurelia

Tags: typescript, aurelia, typedoc

I'm trying to create documentation by using TypeDoc in our Aurelia project. Unfortunately we aren't able to produce any output because TypeDoc cannot resolve modules imports inside the typescript files. Has someone created documentation from a Typescript/aurelia project by using typedoc? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

We're using TypeDoc for our Aurelia Control package and it's quite straightforward.
The NPM script looks like the following:

```
"typedoc": "./node_modules/.bin/typedoc --mode modules --tsconfig ./tsconfig.typedoc.json --out documentation --excludePrivate --theme default --readme readme.md ./src"
```

tsconfig.typedoc.json contains the followings:

```
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
    "files": [
        "src/index.ts"
    ]    
}
```

You can check the result here:
https://community.sensenet.com/api/sn-controls-aurelia/